# Forecasting in R using forecast package

Tags: machine-learning, r

I'm trying to forecast hourly data for 30 days for a process.

I have used the following code:

```
# The packages required for projection are loaded
library("forecast")
library("zoo")

# Data Preparation steps

# There is an assumption that we have all the data for all
# the 24 hours of the month of May
time_index <- seq(from = as.POSIXct("2014-05-01 07:00"),
    to = as.POSIXct("2014-05-31 18:00"), by = "hour")
value <- round(runif(n = length(time_index),100,500))

# Using zoo function , we merge data with the date and hour
# to create an extensible time series object
eventdata <- zoo(value, order.by = time_index)

# As forecast package requires all the objects to be time series objects,
# the below command is used 
eventdata <- ts(value, order.by = time_index)

# For forecasting the values for the next 30 days, the below command is used
z<-hw(t,h=30)
plot(z)
```

I feel the output of this code, is not working fine.
[image]
The forecasted line looks wrong and the dates are not getting correctly projected on the chart.

I'm not sure the fault lies in the data preparation, or if the output is as expected. Any ideas?

Comment: if the plot is only showing may then the forecast is for 30 hours

Comment: close, post it on stack overflow as its an R/programming question.

Comment: Your code doesn't work - `t` isn't defined, `eventdata` is defined twice and not used once, there's no `order.by` arg in the `ts` function on my system etc. Also, this should be on stack overflow since it has ZERO to do with data science.

Comment: Why do you think the forecast is wrong? You fed it random numbers, the best the forecast can do is say "here's the mean and here's the variance, the rest is noise" which is what that forecast is. It CANT do any better.

Comment: Refer this book https://www.otexts.org/fpp/